# Problem in converting string to puny code (in PHP, using phlyLabs's punycode string converter)

Tags: php, utf-8, punycode

i'm using the code from here: http://phlymail.com/en/downloads/idna/download/ and built a function like this (from the example):

```
function convert_to_punycode($inputstring)
{
    $IDN = new idna_convert();
    // The input string, if input is not UTF-8 or UCS-4, it must be converted before
    $inputstringutf8 = utf8_encode($inputstring);
    // Encode it to its punycode presentation
    $outputstringpunycode = $IDN->encode($inputstringutf8);
    return $outputstringpunycode;
}
```

However it doesnt work properly.

> ```
> For the input: Россию
> It gives: Ð Ð¾ÑÑÐ¸Ñ
> Whereas it should give: xn--h1alffa3f
> ```

What am I doing wrong? $inputstring which is being passed is a normal string with no special declarations/etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your string already UTF-8? Looks like it. 
Or is it in ISO-8859-5? 
In both cases you cannot use the PHP function utf8_encode(), since it expects your input string to be ISO-88591-1 (ISO Latin-1, Western European languages). Look into the file transcode_wrapper.php, which is delivered with the class source. This might help you.

Comment: Hi! Thank you! That did seem to be the case and it solved the problem! Muchos gracias!

Answer (score 0):

you might need [PHP IDNA Extension](http://www.xarg.org/project/php-idna/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd just add something like to use if possible the module otherwise Dave suggested function :

```
if(!function_exists('idn_to_ascii') and !function_exists('idn_to_utf8'))
{   define('IDN_FALLBACK_VERSION',2008);
    require_once('idna_convert.class.php');
    function idn_to_ascii($string)
    {   $IDN = new idna_convert(array('idn_version'=>IDN_FALLBACK_VERSION));
        return $IDN->encode($string);
    }
    function idn_to_utf8($string)
    {   $IDN = new idna_convert(array('idn_version'=>IDN_FALLBACK_VERSION));
        return $IDN->decode($string);
    }
    function idn_to_unicode($string){return idn_to_utf8($string);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method to convert encoding

```
//$inputstringutf8 = utf8_encode($inputstring);

$inputstringutf8 = mb_convert_encoding($inputstring, 'utf-8', mb_detect_encoding($inputstring));
```